# How to sync Home Videos on TV app from macOS Catalina 10.15 to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, video, catalina, tv.app

Since the update to Mac OS 10.15 (Catalina) split the iTunes app into Music, TV, and Podcasts I can no longer transfer home videos from my Mac to my iPhone.

I used to do this by:

1. Adding the home video to iTunes.
2. Dragging it to the iPhone icon that appears when the phone is connected via USB cable, and
3. Using 'sync'.

Although the iPhone icon appears at the same place in the TV app, I can no longer drag home videos to it. I also tried right clicking on the iPhone icon and using 'Sync' -- but the home video never syncs onto my iPhone

How do you do this transfer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of iTunes app in macOS Catalina, you can sync content to your iPhone using the Finder app.

The iOS device sync and backup functionality that used to be available within iTunes app in earlier versions of macOS are now available via Finder app.

For instructions, refer to this Apple support document:

- [Use the Finder to sync your iPhone, iPad, or iPod with your computer](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210611)

Comment: This worked! Thanks for teaching me something. Mac OS is getting closer and closer to having a navigable file system.

Comment: @TonyM I am glad you find it helpful :)